# How to remove the horizontal lines of chart & its axis lines in angular?

Tags: apexcharts

Following is an angular app with graphs made of apex charts

https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-column-distributed-d3ns7?from-embed

How can I remove the horizontal lines of that chart & its axis lines (so that this looks much cleaner)

```
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "distibuted",
          data: [21, 22,]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "bar",
        events: {
          click: function(chart, w, e) {
            // console.log(chart, w, e)
          }
        }
      },
      colors: [
        "#008FFB",
        "#00E396",
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          columnWidth: "45%",
          distributed: true
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          ["John", "Doe"],
          ["Joe", "Smith"],
        ],
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: [
              "#008FFB",
              "#00E396",
            ],
            fontSize: "12px"
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

& also how can I format the tooltip colors ?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/

Answer (score 17):

By now you can use this option

```js
chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      id: "basic-bar",
    },
    grid: {
      show: true,      // you can either change hear to disable all grids
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true  //or just here to disable only x axis grids
         }
       },  
      yaxis: {
        lines: { 
          show: true  //or just here to disable only y axis
         }
       },   
    },
  }
```

for more details you can use [this reference](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/grid/)

Answer (score 6):

The grid-lines can be hidden using the following ways.

```
grid: {
    show: false
}
```

or

```js
grid: {
    xaxis: {
        lines: {
            show: false
        }
    },   
    yaxis: {
        lines: {
            show: false
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: In your example, you were missing

```
  <apx-chart
    [grid]="chartOptions.grid"
  ></apx-chart>
```

Answer (score 3):

in your configuration add axisBorder and axisTicks configurations, I couldn't find how to remove the horizontal bars completely though. If I find it I will be back.

```
xaxis
  categories: [
    ["John", "Doe"],
    ["Joe", "Smith"],
  ],
  axisBorder: {
    show: false
  },
  axisTicks: {
    show: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

It's related to grid option! In angular I fixed it like the below

```
export type ChartOptions = {
    series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
    chart: ApexChart;
    dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
    plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
    yaxis: ApexYAxis;
    xaxis: ApexXAxis;
    fill: ApexFill;
    title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
    grid: ApexGrid
};
```

Then in apex config object I did this

```
    constructor() {
        this.chartOptions = {
            grid:{
                show: false
            },
    // other options 
    }
}
```

Also I added grid to HTML as well

```
<div id="chart">
    <apx-chart
        [grid]="chartOptions.grid!"
        [series]="chartOptions.series!"
        [chart]="chartOptions.chart!"
        [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels!"
        [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions!"
        [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis!"
        [fill]="chartOptions.fill!"
        [title]="chartOptions.title!"
    ></apx-chart>
</div>
```